# how to remove legends symbols in highchart when i put legend in external div

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, legend-properties

here the code for extraction

```
    events: {
            load: function () {
          var chart = this;
                $(chart.series).each(function (i, serie) {
                 serie.legendSymbol.destroy();  
                 serie.legendLine.destroy();  
                    $('<li style="color: ' + serie.color + ';text-align:center;border-style:solid;border-width:5px;border-color:+'+ serie.color + ';">' + serie.name + '</li>').click(function () {

                        serie.visible ? serie.hide() : serie.show();

                    }).appendTo('#legend');
                });
            }
        }
```

i wasn't able to remove legends symbols

the answer was given by Halvor Strand

Try adding this style to your

: list-style-type: none;

Comment: What is the "legends symbols"???

Comment: like circle near legend or square or rectangle  etc

Comment: You mean in your external div?

Comment: yep :) i searched and searched and there are many ways to do it in the graph itself but found no answer how to do it to this extraction code...even the destroy (); didn't help...no idea how to

Comment: You say "like circle or square or rectangle", but in external div it is only rectangle? Correct?

Comment: Try adding this style to your `<li>`: `list-style-type: none;`.

Comment: thank you mate, i thought about css...apparently not enough!

Comment: by the way...can you help me with another question....chrome works fine with color part but not android or firefox...